# properties = Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]]()

Tags: scala

```
var properties:Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]] = null
//some code goes here
properties = Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]]()
```

I really don't understand why the second line even exists. Calling the Map class constructor will again initialise the values to some default values and assign it to properties.
Or am I getting it wrong?
So what exactly is happening here?
Am a little new with scala so please bear with me! And I didn't find anything of this sort here!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's someone used to other code, where the variable has or should be be declared at the start of a block, but good style (in that language) is to initialise it near its use. It's not idiomatic Scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
properties = Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]]()
```

Initialize the variable to an empty Map, this is much better than having a `null` as you can call all Map methods without worrying of null pointer exceptions, I don't see why you would want to initialize your variable to `null` honestly.

```
scala> properties = Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]]()
properties: Map[String,Map[String,DProperty]] = Map()

scala> properties.map(x => x.toString)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List()

scala> var properties:Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]] = null
properties: Map[String,Map[String,DProperty]] = null

scala> properties.map(x => x.toString)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Also, I don't know your use case, but note that the scala way would be to use a `val` (immutable variable) instead of a `var` (mutable variable).

Comment: My doubt is that both these statements exist in the code I am reading. So does this mean its plain poor coding or is there something between the lines?

Comment: Yes, to me it looks like poor coding, better have an empty variable than a null.

Comment: @user3851565 Yes, most likely it's bad code. It's possible there is a good reason for this, but quite unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The correct question is why the *first* line exists. Instead, the variable should be initialized immediately:

```
var properties:Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]] = Map.empty // or Map(), no need to repeat the type arguments
```

Don't use `null` unless you have *really*, *really* good reason to.

Answer (score 1):

A Scalish typesafe approach to initialise the mutable `Map` involves the use of `Option`, like this,

```
var properties: Option[Map[String,Map[String, DProperty]]] = None
```

Comment: _Only_ if you actually need to distinguish between "no map" and "empty map". This seems unlikely to be the case here.